# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column :jomes(code 1):, while compiling: select sum(adPrice) from Checkouts Table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm try to query a sum statement in SQLITE database on android studio. But I have got an exception, I even could not find any answer on the web.

Here is my exception :

> "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column :jomes(code
>   1):, while compiling: select sum(adPrice) from CheckoutsTable where
>   username = jomes;"

I have created a table CheckoutsTable and I want to check my username jomes and get the adPrice which is related to that username(I mean by the total).
But it is not working...

Here is my databasehelper;

```
   public int TotalCountStatement(String username)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
        //Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(adPrice) FROM CheckoutsTable WHERE username = jomes;", null);
        int amount;

        Cursor cursor  = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(adPrice) FROM CheckoutsTable WHERE username = jomes;", null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("username"));
            return total;
        }else{
        amount = 0;
        return amount;

        }
        //cursor.close();
    }
```

Please help me to find any answer, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String comparison should be in quotes in SQL. You can use single quotes there '  '

```
Cursor cursor  = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(adPrice) FROM CheckoutsTable WHERE username = 'jomes';", null);
```

Also in the next line you do

```
int total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("username"));
```

This will cause an exception because you are trying to get the index of username column whereas in your select query you have only done `Select SUM`

so instead do

```
int total = cursor.getInt(0);
```

Comment: it works ,however, next it will say after applying your one.. IllegalState Exception: Couldn't read row 0 , col -1 from CurosorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it. –

Comment: That error is because of this line - int total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("username"));

Comment: In this line you are trying to get index of the username column, which is not there because the only thing you have selected is SUM.

Comment: @JamunathHunga just do int total = cursor.getInt(0);

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: it seems another exception there if I applied it "another.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException" String resources ID #0x66. given

Comment: That exception is not because of this. That comes if you use some unknown resource in your UI. :)

Comment: @JamunathHunga If you check this method will now return the correct SUM. Now how you are displaying the count might be causing the error. So you can accept this answer and raise a seperate question with the code related to that UI and we would be happy to help.

Comment: Great happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add single or double quotes around jomes, since the type of the column username is Text (I assume). Like this "jomes".

```
Cursor cursor  = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(adPrice) FROM CheckoutsTable WHERE username = \"jomes\";", null);

Cursor cursor  = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(adPrice) FROM CheckoutsTable WHERE username = 'jomes';", null);
```

Comment: in Android studio gives me a red colour text If i do that, I think android studio cannot recognized as a string because it is inside the double quotes.

Comment: you have to escape it using \ .  Like this: \"jomes\"

Comment: or you can use single quotes: 'jomes'.

Comment: Are you getting a different exception now?

Comment: But, the second one works ,however, next it will say.. IllegalState Exception:
Couldn't read row 0 , col -1 from CurosorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: That seems to be a different error. You have to call `cursor.moveToNext()` and proceed to get data from cursor only if it returns true.

Comment: thanks anyway But, it says couldnt read row 0, the exception again. :)

Comment: check whether you have any data in the cursor. check the value of `cursor.getCount()`